# Recovery after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, fdisk

I know this question has been asked many times and even I have asked it once...But as today I came to know about fdisk so thought of posting it so that someone having good knowledge can help me better.

Here is the log created by fdisk and I would like Ubuntu to show me sda3 and sda4 which its not showing right now and even my windows 7 is not booting up.I have all of my data in one of them and really need it.

Thanks

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3aa63aa5

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63        2047         992+  42  SFS
/dev/sda2   *        2048      206847      102400   42  SFS
/dev/sda3          206848   176334847    88064000   42  SFS
/dev/sda4       466913278   488396799    10741761    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       486445056   488396799      975872   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       466913280   486445055     9765888   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 8075 MB, 8075120640 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 981 cylinders, total 15771720 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
dev/sdb1   *        2048    15771647     7884800    b  W95 FAT32
```

Answer (score 3):

Well sda1, sda2 and sda3 are of SFS type.When Linux reports SFS for MS Windows machines, that generally means that the Windows machine HDD was formatted using Dynamic Volumes.
**Partition type 42** is a Windows specific dynamic partitioning type that Linux may not be fully aware of or feel safe modifying.

They are Pure dynamic disks (those not containing any hard-linked partitions) have only a single partition table entry (type 42) to define the entire disk. Dynamic disks store their volume configuration in a database located in a 1-MB private region at the end of each dynamic disk.

You could follow [this](https://superuser.com/questions/65939/converting-dynamic-to-basic-disk) link to convert your Dynamic hdd to basic hdd.

Comment: I am ready to do all format and have learned a lot in last 2 days so would do a fresh install... http://tinypic.com/r/34g6irb/6  this is my screenshot of Gparted and would like to recover the data in the unallocated space as I have all my important data on that.

Comment: Can I get any help?

Comment: yeah you could use Testdisk to recover your data. you could have a look at this http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html